# Revit API - prompt user to create vertical column

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I am writing a plugin for Revit 2014. One of its features placing a vertical column by the user. Revit API allows placing family instances by the user with the method `PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement`, which is what I'm using, like so:

```
//PillarSymbols is a list containing symbols of various columns available, loaded previously from a file
FamilySymbol symbol = PillarsSymbols.Single(x => x.Kind == selected.Kind).Symbol;
_commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement(symbol);
```

This code enables `Modify | Place structural column` tool in Revit application. It works as desired, but does not allow the user to switch between Vertical Column and Slanted Column. This option is set to whatever it was set before running the code above.

I have tried to set the symbol parameters before running `PromptForFamilyInstancePlacement` using:

```
symbol.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.SLANTED_COLUMN_TYPE_PARAM).Set(value);
```

but `get_Parameter()` above returns `null`.

Is there a method to set column type to Vertical Column, before prompting the user to place the column? Also is there a way to pre-set column height?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't preset the column height but you can adjust the free end of the item created directly afterwards. You should be returning a `FamilyInstance`, so if you grab it again then you can adjust the free end of it.

You may be able to prompt the user to place the correct symbol by cycling through the symbols in the family. Try the snippet below and check to make sure that the symbol produced is the one that you want before placement:

```
FamilySymbol familySymbol = family.Symbols.ForwardIterator().Current as FamilySymbol;
```

Comment: Thank you @prestonsmith for the answer. Unfortunately I can't prompt user to select the right symbol, due to specific requirements of the mentioned plugin, that are irrelevant right now. 
I ended up with a workaround: 
1) have the user place the columns of whichever type would be selected at the moment (Vertical/Slanted) 
2) read locations and rotations of the column instances placed by the user 
3) delete those instances 
4) place my own, vertical instances with my desired height